# Can't create an item using the Neo4Jclient

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I'm trying to programmatically save information to a Neo4J DB using the Neo4Jclient.

I've been trying to follow the examples but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've created a database connection which seems to work, but my code won't compile due to the below line..

```
public void SaveNewRootItem(string child)
    {
        client = new GraphClient(new Uri([ConnectionStringhere]));

        client.Connect();
            client.Cypher
            .Create("(m:LinkItem {child})")
            .WithParams("child", child);
    }
```

According to the examples [on the wiki for the opensource repo](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples) I should be providing parameterised information in "WithParams".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put the code around this up as well? i.e. what is the `child` object?

Comment: I was just starting with a void method, the only thing other than this is the method signature which accepts a sting value defined as child. but I added where I was with it at the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what you're doing, assuming `child` exists, you need to do a couple of changes.
First, you'll want to use `WithParam` not `WithParams`, and after that, to get it into the DB you'll need to `ExecuteWithoutResults()`, so you're query would look like:

```
client.Cypher
    .Create("(m:LinkItem {child})")
    .WithParam("child", child)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

*If* you did want to use `WithParams` you have to supply a dictionary:

```
client.Cypher
    .Create("(m:XX {child})")
    .WithParams(new Dictionary<string, object>{{"child", child}})
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Generally that's useful if you've got a lot of parameters in one query, it all boils down to the same regardless.